# How to use Python with pandas exporting Data to GeoJSON for Google Map

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-maps

I am doing a project about web crawler. 
I will got some point location include (Name, longitude, latitude) 
Then point all of them in Google Map(use Google Map API)

---

First 
I got some data from the website API. -- (300points locaiton) 
Then use Python pandas DataFrame to export Json File

```
df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['name','lat', 'lng'])
df['lat'] = pd.to_numeric(df['lat'])
df['lng'] = pd.to_numeric(df['lng'])

jsonFile = df.to_json(orient='records')
with open('map.json','w') as f:
    f.write(jsonFile)
```

json structure look like this

```
{
"name":"臺中女中",
"lat":24.13604,
"lng":120.6778
}
```

So here is the problem:
How can I import those of point to Google Map use Google Map API
I've tried to read the Google Map API Document, it just tell me to use

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('map.json');
```

Finally i got wrong. and the Error Message

```
uncaught exception: InvalidValueError: not a Feature or FeatureCollection
```

Is Google Map API only support GeoJson?
How can I change my json file to the GeoJson?
or how can I modify my json file that can use in Google Map API.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I change my json file to the GeoJson?

**You could use [geojson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson)**

Here's an example:

Import:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from geojson import Feature, FeatureCollection, Point
```

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': '臺中女中', 'lat': 24.13604, 'lng': 120.6778}])
```

Converting to geojson:

```
# columns used for constructing geojson object
features = df.apply(
    lambda row: Feature(geometry=Point((float(row['lng']), float(row['lat'])))),
    axis=1).tolist()

# all the other columns used as properties
properties = df.drop(['lat', 'lng'], axis=1).to_dict('records')

# whole geojson object
feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features=features, properties=properties)
```

Then you could save your geojson file:

```
with open('/path/to/your/file.geojson', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(feature_collection, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: The properties should really be added at the Feature level rather than at the Feature Collection level.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler would be to use `GeoDataFrame` from the [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) package:

```py
import geopandas

points = geopandas.points_from_xy(x=df.lng, y=df.lat)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=points)
gdf.to_file('file.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
```

This also ensures properties are represented at feature-level, etc.